# Endomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have a question, which may be trivial, but I really don't understand how I should solve the next exercise:

> List all group endomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}_6$.

I consider that I must write down all the functions $f\colon \mathbb{Z}_6\to\mathbb{Z}_6$. But which is the general form of the function?

Comment: Not all the functions: just all the endomorphisms. So, you have to know what an endomorphism is.

Comment: Now you should ask: what are the automorphisms?

Comment: I know what  an endomorphism of a group G  is: the function f:(G,+)→(G,+), with f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b), a,b from G; and f(0)=0. But in my case, I still don't know which is the general form of the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not *all* functions, but only those that are *additive homomorphisms*. That is, only functions $f\colon\mathbb{Z}_6\to\mathbb{Z}_6$ such that $f(a+b) = f(a)+f(b)$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_6$.

1. Show that if $f\colon\mathbb{Z}_6\to\mathbb{Z}_6$ is an additive homomorphism, and you know what $f(1)$ is, then you know what $f(a)$ is for all $a\in\mathbb{Z}$.
2. Determine what values $f(1)$ can be to give you an additive homomorphism.